# Nested Dictionary Syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing program code to record the stock in the nested list to a dictionary using the code as key (e.g., `'3AB'`) and the value is a list containing the stock information without the code (e.g., `["Telcom", "12/07/2018", 1.55, 3000]`). My program code must also be able to access the elements in the nested list.

However, when I run my code, it keeps on hitting syntax error. Can I check what is wrong with my code?

```
stock = {

3AB: {'Name': 'Telcom', 'Purchase Date': '12/12/2018', 'Price': '1.55', 'Volume':'3000'},

S12: {'Name': 'S&P', 'Purchase Date': '12/08/2018', 'Price': '3.25', 'Volume': '2000'},

AE1: {'Name': 'A ENG', 'Purchase Date': '04/03/2018', 'Price': '1.45', 'Volume': '5000'}

}


print(stock[3AB]['Name'])

print(stock[S12]['Name'])

print(stock[AE1]['Name'])
```

Comment: This is not a valid Python data structure, what is `3AB`? Do you mean `'3AB'`?

Comment: Try `'3AB': {'Name': 'Telcom', 'Purchase Date': '12/12/2018', 'Price': '1.55', 'Volume':'3000'},`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

because your dictionary was unhashable. i.e Invalid literal key `3AB`, the correct syntax, being `'3AB'`:

```
stock = {

'3AB': {'Name': 'Telcom', 'Purchase Date': '12/12/2018', 'Price': '1.55', 'Volume':'3000'},

'S12': {'Name': 'S&P', 'Purchase Date': '12/08/2018', 'Price': '3.25', 'Volume': '2000'},

'AE1': {'Name': 'A ENG', 'Purchase Date': '04/03/2018', 'Price': '1.45', 'Volume': '5000'}

}


print(stock['3AB']['Name'])

print(stock['S12']['Name'])

print(stock['AE1']['Name'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
Telcom
S&P
A ENG
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
stock = {

'3AB': {'Name': 'Telcom', 'Purchase Date': '12/12/2018', 'Price': '1.55', 'Volume':'3000'},

'S12': {'Name': 'S&P', 'Purchase Date': '12/08/2018', 'Price': '3.25', 'Volume': '2000'},

'AE1': {'Name': 'A ENG', 'Purchase Date': '04/03/2018', 'Price': '1.45', 'Volume': '5000'}

}


print(stock['3AB']['Name'])

print(stock['S12']['Name'])

print(stock['AE1']['Name'])
```

it throws error because in your code look at 3AB as a variable that it cannot found so you need pass it in '' as string

Answer (score 0):

key must be hashable.your key 3AB must be a string.change into '3AB',the others are the same as 3AB.